# How to fetch nth row in terdata with out using order by

Tags: sql, teradata

How to fetch nth row in teradata without using order by

Comment: You always have to order somehow - how else will we know which row is the nth one?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from <table_name>
qualify (sum(1) over( rows unbounded preceding )) =  <nth_row>
```

Comment: If you run this multiple times for the same value of n, are you guaranteed to always get the same result?  If this is non-deterministic then I don't think you can really call it the nth row.

Comment: @DavidCram: When there's no Order By Teradata will simply add one (probably for internal processing) over all columns :-) So probably a deterministic result, but nothing close to a nth row :-)

Comment: @dnoeth I understand that it adds 1 for each row.  I'm just not sure what kind of evil sorcery it uses to decide the order in which rows are returned :-).  I had always sort of assumed that the numbering sequence depended on which amps happen to return data first.  However, running it a few times does seem to consistently give me the same result.  So my assumption may have been wrong

Comment: likely based on the primary index

Comment: If I do `select * from table`, it comes in the exact same order every time, far as I can tell.  If I run `select top N from table` with no order by, I get the same rows every time, as far as I can tell.  However, those top n rows are not the same as the first N rows I get from select *.   And finally, this is really silly.  I will never understand what people actually want in these kinds of questions.